# New to Java and coding in general

Tags: java

Teacher is making us code and we're legit just a week or so in intro to programming with java and she's already making us do this. I'm absolutely clueless. This is the pseudocode.

### Pseudocode

> 1. Create variables:  speed, time and distance
> 2. Store 20 in the variable speed
> 3. Store 10 in the variable time
> 4. Multiply speed * time and store the result in the variable distance
> 5. Display The distance is followed by the  value of the distance variable.

Kind regards.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).

Comment: I think you should maybe try to look up basically any beginner Java tutorial and try to solve it from there. Someone just posting it for you will never help you understand it. Also some formatting would go a long way :D

Comment: For what it is worth, if you have had more than one hour of beginners training in Java, you *should* be able to do this without help.  (IMO)  This is only a bit more complicated than a "hello world" program.

Answer (score 2):

To **create** a variable, you must tell Java its **type** and **name**. Creating a variable is also called **declaring** a variable. When you create a primitive variable Java will set aside enough bits in memory for that primitive type and associate that memory location with the name that you used. You have to tell Java the type of the variable because Java needs to know how many bits to use and how to represent the value.

This is the list of Java Primitive Data Types:

[image: img]

Notice that the different types get a different amount of space. When you declare a variable, a memory location (sequential number of bits) is set aside for a variable of that type and the name is associated with that location. An integer gets 32 bits of space, a double gets 64 bits of space and a boolean could be represented by just one bit, but the amount of space isn’t specified by the Java standard.

### Ok Teo, I got it, but how to declare (create) a variable?

Well my young padawan, you need to specify the type, leave at least one space, then the name for the variable and end the line with a semicolon `;`.

#### Teo, why a semicolon?

Well, like in English, we use a dot to represent the end of a sentence, in Java we use a semicolon `;` to show the end of a Java statement.

### Teo, how can I know what type should I use?

Good question young one. It depends on your definition. For example, Java uses the keyword `int` for integer, `float` and `double` for a floating point number (a double precision number), and `boolean` for a Boolean value (`true` or `false`) as shown in the image.

Now let's try to make some code, so you can understand:

#### 1. Create variables: `speed`, `time` and `distance`

For your pseudo code let's assume that all the numbers are integer so we will use the type `int` like this:

```java
public class VariableDeclaration
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     int speed;
     int time;
     int distance;
   }
}
```

Because they are all integers you can declare all of them at once in one line using coma `,` like this:

```java
public class VariableDeclaration
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     int speed, time, distance;
   }
}
```

Well we have declared our variables but they have not been initialized to any value yet.

#### 2. Store 20 in the variable `speed` and Store 10 in the variable `time`

This part of the exercise will assign a value to our declared variables like this:

```java
public class VariableDeclaration
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     int speed, time, distance;
     speed = 20;
     time = 10;
   }
}
```

The equal sign here `=` doesn’t mean the same as it does in a mathematical equation where it implies that the two sides are equal. Here it means store the value in the space (box) associated with the name on the left to the value on the right. In this example, we assigned the value `20` to the variable `speed` and the value `10` to the variable `time`.

You can also specify an initial value for the variable by adding an equals sign `=` followed by the value when you declare the variable like this.

```java
public class VariableDeclaration
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     int speed = 20;
     int time = 10;

     int distance;
   }
}
```

Notice that the variable distance has not been initialized, yet.

#### 3. Multiply `speed * time` and store the result in the variable `distance`

Remember that a variable holds a value and that value can change or vary. In this example, you can assign the result of multiplying `speed` and `time` to the variable `distance`. You can do this as shown below:

```java
public class VariableDeclaration
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     int speed = 20;
     int time = 10;

     int distance = speed * time;
   }
}
```

#### 4. Display The distance is followed by the value of the distance variable.

Finally, you can simply use `System.out.println()` to send output to standard output (screen).

```java
public class VariableDeclaration
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     int speed = 20;
     int time = 10;

     int distance = speed * time;

     System.out.println(distance);
   }
}
```

Remember that `println()` method prints a string inside the brackets. Then the cursor moves to the beginning of the next line.

Also we can use the single line declaration like this:

```java
public class VariableDeclaration
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     int speed, time, distance;

     speed = 20;
     time = 10;
     distance = speed * time;

     System.out.println(distance);
   }
}
```